# CSS style wont apply in text input boxes

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I am having trouble with applying a style in my input box.
I have header.css here

```
@charset "utf-8";
    body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div, ul, li  {
margin:0;
padding:0;
    }

    body { font family: Verdana; background-color: #FFFFFF }

    #Wrapper {
width: auto;
height:2000px;
margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #divHeader {
position:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 180px;
background:url(thisheader/header_1.png)
    }

    #divHeader2 {
position: 180px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: url(thisheader/SMCFIbanner.png);
    }

    #box {
background: white;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
border-radius: 1px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #DDD inset;
color: #666;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: 185px;
outline: none;
    }
```

when I try to apply the style to the textbox for the password and username using the header.css, it wont apply. I created a new css file just to check, yes.css:

```
   input#box {
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #DDD inset;
        color: #666;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 165px;
        outline: none;
    }
```

**log.php**

```
<div>
<form method="post" action="checkLogin.php">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="myusername" size="20%" class="input_field" title="username" id="box" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" value="" name="mypassword" class="input_field" title="password" id="box" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" alt="login" id="submit_btn" title="Login" />
</form>
</div>
```

and when i try to link this one in my log.php, it worked.

what might be the problem ?

Comment: @Deryck There's two `input` element with a same `id` attribute in the markup you've added.

Comment: Have you reset your cache? Ctrl + F5

Comment: Yeah I just copy and pasted what he put up here.  That's probably part of his problem lol

Comment: Weird thing is I left it as-is this whole time and my fiddle is working as it should and formatting correctly.

Comment: how you are including  header.css in your file ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WVqvH/

Comment: @RaviJethva, like this <html>
<head>
 <title>
 SMCFI-YSLEP
 </title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="header.css"/>
</head>
<body>

Comment: @Deryck whoa. in that site you link, it appears well. i used the code and paste it on mine, replaced the former codes, but it still wont apply. why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try styling the input box like this:

```
input[type=text] {
background: white;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
border-radius: 1px;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #DDD inset;
color: #666;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: 185px;
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, as well as the other answers mentioned but its still not applying.

Comment: Hmm, that is really strange, can you show us how do you include the CSS file in the HTML code ? The only issue that comes in my head is you don't include it properly.

Comment: like this, <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="header.css"/> it is really strange, indeed. as i said, i tried seperating the style for the inputs and put it into another css file, load that file instead, and it worked. but when i incude it to my real css file, the one that i am really using, it wont apply.

Comment: There has to be a conflict in your CSS file, did you style input box before in the CSS ? When the page loads, no design is applied at all, or a different one is applied ? CSS loads the first style and ignores the rest, meaning if you styled input box once, it won't style it the second time.

Comment: there isn't any style at all. should i try to re-do all this stuff?

Comment: Clean your cache memory, can't figure out why a chunk of CSS code won't get loaded, if it is properly done, which seems to be in your case.

Comment: you see, in this site (credits to @Deryck), my form should look like this, but when i run it in my browser, a single style isn't applied at all, even font types.

Comment: Can I have a link to your website ? There has to be something keeping it away from loading, a spelling mistake, anything.

Comment: Did you clean your cache as I told you ?

Comment: i just finished emptying my chache

Comment: still not applying style :(

Comment: Hmm. Can you try to include the style in the page with:
<style> and </style> tags ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should not have multiple elements on page with the same id.  In this case, both your login and password fields have an ID of "box".  Use class instead.  You may be better off doing:

```
<div id='box'>
<form method="post" action="checkLogin.php">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="myusername" size="20%" class="input_field" title="username" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" value="" name="mypassword" class="input_field" title="password"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" alt="login" id="submit_btn" title="Login" />
</form>
</div>
```

Then, in the css, do

```
#box input[type='text']{
   blah,blah,blah...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, as well as the other answers mentioned but its still not applying.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you have two elements with the same id.
By the way, you can select to apply the style to all input textfields with this selector.

```
   form input[type=text] {
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-radius: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px #DDD inset;
        color: #666;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        width: 165px;
        outline: none;
    }
```